# How would one recognize a /this font? (pictures for the specific font included)

Tags: font-identification

I need to find out what font was this written with:

[image]

I have already tried http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ but it didn't help.
Do you know of some sites that display galleries of known fonts? I've only managed to get to bizzare fonts for some reason.

Anyway, any solution is welcome,
thx

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on in those characters given the small size.

Comment: It does look like an lcd font with photoshop blend mode dissolve added to it.

Answer (score 1):

The sample image is way too small to guess accurately but as far as I can see this is some kind of LCD font, and the shape of -W- gives a single match (among LCD fonts) on MyFonts - [LCD SH](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/efscangraphic/lcd-sh/)